# Prove that the topological group $\mathrm{SO}(k,l)$, where $k,l$ are positive, has two connected components.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Letting $n=k+l$, we define the matrix $Q\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$Q_{ij}=\begin{cases} 0 & i\neq j \\ 1 & 1\leq i=j\leq k \\ -1 & k+1\leq i=j\leq n\end{cases}$$ and we set $$\mathrm{SO}(k,l):=\{A\in\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})\ |\ A^\mathrm{T}QA=Q\}$$ with the subspace topology given by $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. This is exercise 7.2* of *Representation Theory, a First Course*, by Fulton and Harris.

My usual tool for finding components is by using the determinant function, but clearly that doesn't apply here. The book suggests using the projection mappings $$\pi_1:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k,\ (v_1,\ldots,v_n)\mapsto(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$$ and $$\pi_2:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^l,\ (v_1,\ldots,v_n)\mapsto(v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n)$$ and associating to any automorphism $A\in\mathrm{SO}(k,l)$ and automorphism of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and of $\mathbb{R}^l$ by means of these projections, and then looking at whether or not these resulting automorphisms preserve the orientation of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mathbb{R}^l$. Firstly, though, I don't see how we even have that for $A\in\mathrm{SO}(k,l),\ A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $A\circ\pi_1$ even maps into $\mathrm{im}(\pi_1)$, and $A\circ\pi_2$ into $\mathrm{im}(\pi_2)$.

I can see that $\pi_1(v)=v$ if and only if $Qv=v$, and that $\pi_2(v)=v$ if and only if $Qv=-v$, and I suspect that this fact is necessary, but I haven't been able to successfully use this fact.

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your formula for defining $SO(k,l)$ is wrong, it should be $SL_n(R)$, not $SO_n(R)$.

Comment: OK, it's fixed now.

Comment: To see that $A$ restricts to an automorphism on $\mathbb{R}^k$, write $A$ as a block matrix, with $k \times k$ matrix $X$ in the upper left block and $l \times k$ matrix $Y$ in the lower left block (the other blocks don't matter at the moment.)  Using the defining relationship for $SO(k,l)$, it follows that $X^TX - Y^TY = I$.  Now, if $Xv = 0$, then $Y^TYv = -v$.  But $Y^TY$ is positive semi-definite and can't have a negative eigenvalue, so $v = 0$.  It follows that $X$ is injective and thus, for dimension reasons, an isomorphism.

Comment: Can you help me to see why the defining relationship for $SO(k,l)$ implies that $X^tX - Y^tY = I$?